# Clickable image that expands parts of it

Tags: javascript, html, drupal

I am trying to make an interactive map of the US, one where you click on a state, the state expands "above the rest of the states" and in it gives some small description of the chosen state. 
I tried looking up things like this and found things along the lines of what I'm looking for but not quite the same. I learned that I need to use svg's but I'm having a hard time finding some guidance on how to perform what I need.

Comment: `interactive map of the US` seems interesting. Can you post your code friend?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would paste the image of the USA map into the page.

Then I would use the HTML `<map>` feature to create hyperlinks to 'each area of the map' that you wanted to 'link'. Then, I would hyperlink them to different pages (or tooltip via CSS) that would contain more detailed information regarding the specific US State.

If you've not used the `<map>` feature before, here is a simple rundown:

```
<img src="XXX" width="XXX" height="XXX" alt="XXX" usemap="#mapname">

<map name="mapname">
    <area shape="rect" coords="SEE BELOW" href="XXX" alt="XXX">
</map>
```

The `coords="XXX"` attribute must be formatted in this way: `coords="x1,y1,x2,y2"` where:

```
x1 = top left X coordinate
y1 = top left Y coordinate
x2 = bottom right X coordinate
y2 = bottom right Y coordinate
```

**Please note:**
 1. The `usemap="#mapname"` attribute must include the `#`.
 2. You must put your own info where `XXX` has been placed.
 3. You do not need to include `href="XXX"` in `<area>` if you are going to use the Tooltip function using CSS. This would be required if you were going to link each USA State to a different dedicated page.

If you wanted to explore the CSS Tooltips options, this would be a good start: `https://kazzkiq.github.io/balloon.css/`.

There are other ways of doing it using CSS only, or using Javascript/JQuery, but this would be a pure HTML method to use, a quite handy one at that.

Hope this helps.